# Getting rid of proxy method

Tags: angular

At the moment I'm initially checking if an item should be selected or not:

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.emoneyProducts"
                 [selected]="isInShoppingCart(menuItem)"
                 [value]="menuItem">
    {{ menuItem.title }} {{ menuItem.price | currencyFormat }}
</mat-list-option>
```

However, the value to be checked is in an observable, so I had to create a proxy-function for that:

```
...
export class DialogRestaurantComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

    constructor() {
        this.shoppingCart$.subscribe(menuItems => this.shoppingCartItems = menuItems);
    }

    ...

    isInShoppingCart(menuItem: any) {
        return this.shoppingCartItems.find((shoppingCartItem: any) =>
            shoppingCartItem.id === menuItem.id) !== undefined;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of `isInShoppingCart`, so bind `shoppingCart$` straight to `[selected]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a ngModel or ReactiveForm to the whole list:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-selection-list formControlName="subscriptions">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let subscription of subscriptions" [value]="subscription.id">
            {{subscription.name}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
</ng-container>
```

The value of the FormControl will contain an array of all the values that are checked in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **no**.

You want to bind an observable to a condition that checks on a boolean. This isn't possible (well, it is, but it relies on truthy/falsy rather than if your item is in the cart).

A "simpler" way if you want is

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.emoneyProducts"
                 [selected]="selected.includes(menuItem.id)"
                 (click)="selected.includes(menuItem.id) ? selected.push(menuItem.id) : selected.slice(selected.indexOf(menuItem.id, 1))"
                 [value]="menuItem">
```

in your component TS you will only have:

```
selected: string[] = [];
```

Algorithm :

- Item is selected if its id is contained in the selected array
- On click, check if the item id is in the array

  - If it is, then remove it
  - If it is not, then add it